# Text in my array is not ending up in my table view cell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I cannot seem to find my error can anyone help me? When I attempt to run test the application it works but when I click on the Calendar segue it shows me a blank uitableview list. I want it to show me the "event" in the text

My NSLOG details about the array:

2014-08-08 17:38:28.391 nths[2899:607] array contents: (
    " {\n    Date = \"9/14/14\";\n    Information = \"Mrs. Ford's Room\";\n    event = Meeting;\n}",
    " {\n    Date = \"9/14/19\";\n    Information = \"ford room\";\n    event = \"lunch at bravos\";\n}"
)

Here are is all of the code that I think would affect this.

CalendarViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <Parse/Parse.h>
#import "DataCellViewController.h"

@interface CalendarViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDelegate> {
    NSArray *eventArray;
}

@property (weak, nonatomic)IBOutlet UITableView *Datatable;

@end
```

CalendarViewController.m

```
#import "CalendarViewController.h"

@interface CalendarViewController ( )

@end

@implementation CalendarViewController

@synthesize Datatable;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    [self performSelector:@selector(retrieveFromParse)];
}

- (void) retrieveFromParse {

    PFQuery *retrieveDate = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Calendar"];

    [retrieveDate findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
           NSLog(@"%@",objects);
    if (!error) {
            eventArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:objects];
        }
        [Datatable reloadData];
    }];
}

//Setup table of folder names

//get number of sections in tableview
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1;
}

//get number of rows by counting number of folders
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return eventArray.count;
    }

   //setup cells in tableView
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath        *)indexPath

    {

    //setup cell
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"CalenderCell";
    DataCellViewController *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
            cell = [[DataCellViewController alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault    reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        }


// Configure the cell...

        NSDictionary *tempDict = [eventArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

        cell.eventTitle.text = [tempDict objectForKey:@"event"];


    NSLog(@"array contents: %@", eventArray);

   return cell;
}



    - (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
    {
       [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

@end
```

DataCellViewController.h

```
    #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

    @interface DataCellViewController : UITableViewCell

    @property (nonatomic, strong)IBOutlet UILabel *eventTitle;

    @end
```

DataCellViewController.m

```
#import "DataCellViewController.h"

@interface DataCellViewController ( )

@end

@implementation DataCellViewController

@synthesize eventTitle;

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    if (self) {
       // Initialization code
     }
    return self;
 }

- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super setSelected:selected animated:animated];
    // Configure the view for the selected state
}

@end
```

Comment: You also need to conform to <UITableViewDataSource> in CalendarViewController.

Comment: How can I do that? Sorry I am new to this and I am trying to learn it.

Comment: @interface CalendarViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDelegate>, <UITableViewDataSource> {  ...just add as shown.

Comment: @russoandrew22 one hour ago you asked [same question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25211632/uitableview-with-parse-error-help-nsinternalinconsistencyexception) and marked as duplicate. Please edit your question if you did not get any proper answer instead of posting new one.

Comment: Also your event Array should really be a property.

Comment: It gives the error as follows: Expected identifier or '('

Comment: Then you typed it wrong.

Comment: @mohacs I fixed that problem this is a new issue...

Comment: You don't need to conform to that. Your array contents look like a string not a dictionary.

Comment: `#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>`
`#import <Parse/Parse.h>`
`#import "DataCellViewController.h"`

`@interface ViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDataSource>`

`@end`

`@interface CalendarViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDelegate>`

`@property(strong, nonatomic)NSArray *eventArray;`


`@property (weak, nonatomic)IBOutlet UITableView *Datatable;`

`@end`

Comment: It say expected identifier '(' on the second @ interface line

Comment: @desdenova do you know what is wrong?

Comment: Don't put code in your comments. Edit your question to include the code you are now using.

Comment: Does anyone know what is wrong?